# Edit Javascript to align properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'm using infinite-scroll to pull up new posts. To ensure the posts pull up in 3 columns instead of 1, I am calling Javascript after the next posts are fetched:

```
jQuery(newElements).makeacolumnlists({
      cols: 3, 
      colWidth: 305, 
      equalHeight: 'ul', 
      startN: 1
});
```

What do I need to change for making the fetched posts align properly with the other post on top? The posts on top are stacked li elements and the plugin is stacking divs. Any way to fix this?

My site is (removed)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.li_container {padding-left: 0px}
```

should solve your problem. And this will move all post 25px to the right,

```
#li_container1 {margin-left: 25px}
```

Comment: @user1429400, it seems `#li_container1 {margin-left: 25px}` does that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the new posts are inside a `<div id="li_container2" class=li_container>` (which itself is inside li_container1) which is why it has twice the margin.
Just add the new div outside the old container.